# Ordering by last active time but weighted by gender

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by

I am currently ordering by a user's last active time, where the most recently active users show up at the top.

```
"profile".last_active_time DESC NULLS LAST,
"profile".id DESC
```

I'd like to show more females towards the top, so I tried this, but clearly it ends up showing all females at the top first.

```
CASE WHEN "profile_date:gender_type".type_id = 'FEMALE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
"profile".last_active_time DESC NULLS LAST,
"profile".id DESC
```

How would I order by last active time mostly, but weighted so females get a little more priority to have a possible chance to show up in front of say, a male that was active more recently within the same day?

Example:

- male last active 1 hour ago, female last active 1 week ago => male shows up first
- male last active 1 hour ago, female last active 2 hours ago => female has a chance of showing up before male

At the moment, user A always shows up before user B if A was last active before B. If user A is male and user B is female, and A was last active before B, A still always shows up before B. I want it so that if user A is male and user B is female, and A was last active before B, B *might* show up before A.

It doesn't have to be done by explicit time periods, and I would imagine `random()` weighted percentages would work. Doesn't have to be perfect.

Comment: How do you define this *little more priority*?

Comment: You can compare last active time of male and female. And if difference is less than 24 hours ie same day show female. If time difference is more than 24 hours then show recent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give females 1 hour ahead like this:

```
ORDER BY 
    "profile".last_active_time + CASE 
        WHEN "profile_date:gender_type".type_id = 'FEMALE' THEN time '01:00' 
        ELSE time '00:00' 
    END DESC NULLS LAST,
    "profile".id DESC
```

Comment: Clever, amazing solution! I really like the effect. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Convert `last_active_time` to a time in the past, then weight that time however you choose.

```
order by 
    (now()-last_active_time) * case when type_id = 'FEMALE' then 0.5 else 1.0 end, 
    id desc;
```